# Should "State" be capitalized on its own?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization, proper-nouns

Say we had the following:

> Higher Education spending, clout, and influence in New York State is substantial. Within the **State’s** borders...

Should the latter instance of *State* be capitalized or not?

Comment: The latter instance of "state" should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other. First, [here's the general pattern for AmE...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfD7V.png)
[image]

[...and for BrE...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20state%20pays,the%20State%20pays&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%20state%20pays;,c0;.t1;,the%20State%20pays;,c0)

[image]

Those charts suggest that the modern trend (led by American usage, with Brits rapidly catching up) is *not* to capitalise.

---

Perhaps because I'm British and/or because I'm over 50, I tend to capitalise "the State" when I mean *the British Government, Civil Service, NHS, etc., **collectively***, on the grounds that I think of it as [proper noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proper-noun) referencing a single entity (the British State). But I *don't* capitalise forms such as [state-sponsored industries](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22state-sponsored%20industries%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), because it's a more "general-purpose" reference (to *any* nation-state).

I'm not going to wade through 46,700 (not case-sensitive) results in Google Books for passages containing [BOTH "new york state" AND "the state pays"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20state%20pays%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%2b%22new%20york%20state%22%20%2b%22the%20state%20pays%22&tbm=bks), but I have to say my impression from glancing through the first few pages is that most of them *are* capitalised (in both terms).

Comment: Most excellent and much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I would say not, because in the second sentence it is no longer specified, but then I'm a mere Brit.

Comment: I'd say you could argue either way - the word could be regarded as generic, or a shortening of "New York State's" along these lines: _We went to watch "The Pirates of Penzance" last week. "The Pirates" has been showing for several months at_ . . .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here's my preferred method. When referring to the state or city as a generic territory, don't capitalize it. *The state of Texas has 15,000 citizens. The city has rich culture.* However, when the words have to do with governmental bodies, capitalize them to recognize their formality. *The State of California owes Wall Street millions in debt! The City will vote tomorrow in a hearing. The State declared the contract invalid.* Therefore, my preferred opinion is to lowercase *state* in the question, as the governmental part is not prioritized in the sentence.

Comment: This seems sensible, but of course it falls down when using New York State. Whether or not << state of new york >> needs three capital letters because it is a 4-word compound proper noun is a matter for politicians to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Would you write *Maine state*, *New Hampshire state*, or even *Rhode Island and Providence Plantations state* or would you have the word *`state`* [camelized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)? FYI, the full name of Rhode Island is the longest name of any state in the Union.

See, if you cannot write Maine **State** (or Rhode Island and Providence Plantations **State**), rather than Maine **state**, with a clear conscience, than for equality's sake you should not be able to write New York **State** or Washington **State**.

Would you write Pennsylvania State or state?

When you write *Maine State Lottery* or *New Your State Police*, you would not actually be writing *Maine State* or *New York State*, but *Maine {State Lottery}* and *New York {State Police}*, especially that these are proper names of entities within those states.

However, due to state/regional patriotism, people in Florida for example, might actually write *Florida State*. That would be like asking if the word *gods* should be camelized. Therefore, people outside the patriotic sense of Florida should write *Florida state*, as people with no allegiance or faith in gods would write *gods*, uncamelized.

However, New York is a special case. There exists a need to differentiate the city of New York from the state of New York. Since we would write as *New York City*, normalization of naming convention would require us to write as *New York State*, regardless of where your allegiance lie.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Comment: "There exists a need to differentiate the city of New York from the state of New York." 
You don't see need to differentiate the city of Washington from the state of Washington? Or does "DC" do that? If so, then why do people feel compelled to add "state" after "Washington"?

Comment: Are you planning to write a rule book or fatwa on it?

Comment: LOL. No, just wondering. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to say this is "If it's part of a pronoun it's capitalized, otherwise it isn't".

Eg "Washington State students are protesting on tuesday"

"Students are protesting against the state government on tuesday"

"Washington State is one of the more northerly states of the USA".

Answer (score 0):

Almost five years and 82,000 views after this question was posted, no one has yet cited the advice from an actual style guide. Let me break the ice by quoting advice from four major U.S. style guides.

From *The Associated Press Style Book* (2007):

> **state** Lowercase in all *state of* constructions: *the state of Maine*, *the states of Maine and Vermont*.
>
> ...
>
> Do not capitalize *state* when used simply as an adjective to specify a level of jurisdiction: *state Rep. William Smith*, *the state Transportation Department funds*.
>
> Apply the same principle to phrases such as *the city of Chicago*, *the town of Auburn*, etc.

AP's position on lowercasing *state* also applies to instances where the word follows the state's name:

> **state names** Follow these guidelines: ... Use *New York state* when necessary to distinguish the state from New York City. Use *state of Washington* or *Washington state* when necessary to distinguish the state from the District of Columbia. (*Washington State* is the name of a university in the state of Washington.)

From *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010):

> **8.50 *Political divisions—capitalization*.** Words denoting political divisions—from *empire*, *republic*, and *state* down to *ward* and *precinct*—are capitalized when they follow a name and are used as an accepted part of the name. When preceding the name, such terms are  usually capitalized in names of countries but lowercased in entities below the national level [cross reference omitted]. Used alone they are usually lowercased.
>
> [Relevant examples:] Washington State; the state of Washington[;] the New England states

From *Words into Type*, third edition (1974):

> **Divisions of the World or of a country.** Cap names of the divisions of the world or of a country.
>
> [Relevant examples:] North Atlantic States[;] New York State
>
> Lowercase: state {used in a general sense and when it does not follow a proper name: state of New York, state of Oklahoma} ...

From Allan Siegal & William Connolly, *The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage*, revised edition (1999):

> **state.** Capitalize *New York State*, *Washington State* and formal references to any state of government: *The State of Ohio brought the suit*. Lowercase *state* in references to a geographic area (*They drove through the state of Illinois*) and when it stands alone (*The state sued the city*). Capitalize when *State* appears with the name of an official agency or with an official title that is capitalized: *the State Education Department*; *State Treasurer Pat Y. Berenich*. Use state in reference to New York and Washington when necessary to distinguish them from the cities, but omit *State* if the context is unmistakable: *The governors of California and New York have similar powers*. *Nebraska's population is smaller than Washington's*. Lowercase in the general sense: affairs of state.

Overall, the four style guides I've cited offer fairly consistent advice on several points, although AP breaks with the other three on the appropriateness of initial-capping *State* following *New York* or *Washington* (in part to make clear that the state is intended and not New York City or Washington, D.C.) and doesn't make an exception to the general rule against capitalizing *state* in "state of X" constructions in cases involving formal references to state governnments of the form "State of Idaho." All four guides advise against initial-capping *state* when it appears in informal, descriptive contexts.

With regard to the poster's question, I think, *Chicago*, *Words into Type*, and the *New York Times* would endorse this approach to capping/lowercasing the posted text:

> Higher-education spending, clout, and influence in New York State are substantial. Within the state’s borders...

But AP would favor this treatment:

> Higher-education spending, clout, and influence in New York state are substantial. Within the state’s borders...

The most surprising split in preference is the one between AP and the *New York Times*. On most points, the *Times* follows AP style—which makes sense because AP style governs the form used in AP wire service stories. The *Times*'s decision in favor of "New York State" and "Washington State" means that someone at the newspaper has to go through all AP articles and initial-cap the word *state* whenever one of those two phrases appears.

Comment: Just want to point out that they don't agree. AP says to make it lower case; the other three say cap it.

Comment: @RodneyAtkins: You are correct. I have reworked the erroneous parts of my original answer to reflect reality. Thanks for pointing out the situation with AP style.