# Is the capitalization correct? ...and ensures proper coordination among State and local criminal justice agencies

Tags: capitalization

Is the capitalization correct in the bold section of following partial sentance

...and ensures proper coordination among **State and local criminal justice agencies**

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139941/should-state-be-capitalized-on-its-own

Comment: Yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: Not for AmE it isn't......

Comment: @Lambie It has its uses, in *any* English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely a matter of preference. In official documents produced by  government agencies, words like Federal, State, County, etc., are commonly capitalized. This was once widespread practice in mainstream media publications as well, and you will continue to see these words capitalized in various non-official documents. However, this is not nearly as common as it once was. Capitalizing words like *federal* and *state* does nothing to aid readability, and meaning remains unchanged whether you capitalize or not, and so it is generally considered unnecessary. In fact, many editors believe capital letters are a distraction because they imbue a certain value to words that in many cases is not warranted. Words like "state" and "federal" are really no different than any other noun or adjective--they carry no more weight than words like "local" or "nationwide," so, in the opinion of many, they should be treated identically, i.e., not capitalized.

Comment: You're nearly there.